# Python pandas show repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get data from txt file with pandas.read_csv but it doesn't show the repeated(same) values in the file such as  I have 2043 in the row but It shows it once not in every row.

**My file sample**

[image]

**Result set**

[image]

All the circles I've drawn should be 2043 also but they are empty.

My code is :

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('samplefile.txt', sep='\t', header=None,
               names = ["234",  "235",  "236"]
```

Comment: Just for your information: The data is NOT missing/lost, it is just not shown for convenience and structured data presentation. So imho just leaving it as a multi index is quite useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get `MultiIndex`, so first level value are not shown only.

You can convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Or specify each column in parameter names for avoid `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('samplefile.txt', sep='\t', names = ["one","two","next", "234", "235", "236"]
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for I'll click to accept it as an answer. Thank you  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

A word of warning with `MultiIndex` as I was bitten by this yesterday and wasted time trying to trouble shoot a non-existant problem.

If one of your index levels is of type `float64` then you may find that the indexes are *not* shown in full.  I had a dataframe I was `df.groupby().describe()` and the variable I was performing the `groupby()` on was originally a long `int`, at some point it was converted to a `float` and when printing out this index was rounded.  There were a number of values very close to each other and so it *appeared* on printing that the `groupby()` had found multiple levels of the second index.

Thats not very clear so here is an illustrative example...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = np.random.uniform(low=89908893132829,
                          high=89908893132929,
                          size=(50,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'obs': np.arange(100)},
                  index=np.append(index, index)).sort_index()
df.index.name = 'index1'
df['index2'] = [1, 2] * 50
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index(['index1', 'index2'], inplace=True)
```

Look at the dataframe and it appears that there is only one level of index1...

```
df.head(10)
                     obs
index1       index2     
8.990889e+13 1         4
             2        54
             1        61
             2        11
             1        89
             2        39
             1        65
             2        15
             1        60
             2        10
```

`groupby(['index1', 'index2']).describe()` and it *looks* like there is only one level of `index1`...

```
summary = df.groupby(['index1', 'index2']).describe()
summary.head()
                      obs                                        
                    count  mean std   min   25%   50%   75%   max
index1       index2                                              
8.990889e+13 1        1.0   4.0 NaN   4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
             2        1.0  54.0 NaN  54.0  54.0  54.0  54.0  54.0
             1        1.0  61.0 NaN  61.0  61.0  61.0  61.0  61.0
             2        1.0  11.0 NaN  11.0  11.0  11.0  11.0  11.0
             1        1.0  89.0 NaN  89.0  89.0  89.0  89.0  89.0
```

But if you look at the actual values of `index1` in either you see that there are multiple unique values.  In the original dataframe...

```
df.index.get_level_values('index1')

Float64Index([89908893132833.12, 89908893132833.12, 89908893132834.08,
              89908893132834.08, 89908893132835.05, 89908893132835.05,
               89908893132836.3,  89908893132836.3, 89908893132837.95,
              89908893132837.95,  89908893132838.1,  89908893132838.1,
               89908893132838.6,  89908893132838.6, 89908893132841.89,
              89908893132841.89, 89908893132841.95, 89908893132841.95,
              89908893132845.81, 89908893132845.81, 89908893132845.83,
              89908893132845.83, 89908893132845.88, 89908893132845.88,
              89908893132846.02, 89908893132846.02,  89908893132847.2,
               89908893132847.2, 89908893132847.67, 89908893132847.67,
               89908893132848.5,  89908893132848.5,  89908893132848.5,
               89908893132848.5, 89908893132855.17, 89908893132855.17,
              89908893132855.45, 89908893132855.45, 89908893132864.62,
              89908893132864.62, 89908893132868.61, 89908893132868.61,
              89908893132873.16, 89908893132873.16,  89908893132875.6,
               89908893132875.6, 89908893132875.83, 89908893132875.83,
              89908893132878.73, 89908893132878.73,  89908893132879.9,
               89908893132879.9, 89908893132880.67, 89908893132880.67,
              89908893132880.69, 89908893132880.69, 89908893132881.31,
              89908893132881.31, 89908893132881.69, 89908893132881.69,
              89908893132884.45, 89908893132884.45, 89908893132887.27,
              89908893132887.27, 89908893132887.83, 89908893132887.83,
               89908893132892.8,  89908893132892.8, 89908893132894.34,
              89908893132894.34,  89908893132894.5,  89908893132894.5,
              89908893132901.88, 89908893132901.88, 89908893132903.27,
              89908893132903.27, 89908893132904.53, 89908893132904.53,
              89908893132909.27, 89908893132909.27, 89908893132910.38,
              89908893132910.38, 89908893132911.86, 89908893132911.86,
               89908893132913.4,  89908893132913.4, 89908893132915.73,
              89908893132915.73, 89908893132916.06, 89908893132916.06,
              89908893132922.48, 89908893132922.48, 89908893132923.44,
              89908893132923.44, 89908893132924.66, 89908893132924.66,
              89908893132925.14, 89908893132925.14, 89908893132928.28,
              89908893132928.28],
             dtype='float64', name='index1')
```

...and in the summarised dataframe...

```
summary.index.get_level_values('index1')

Float64Index([89908893132833.12, 89908893132833.12, 89908893132834.08,
              89908893132834.08, 89908893132835.05, 89908893132835.05,
               89908893132836.3,  89908893132836.3, 89908893132837.95,
              89908893132837.95,  89908893132838.1,  89908893132838.1,
               89908893132838.6,  89908893132838.6, 89908893132841.89,
              89908893132841.89, 89908893132841.95, 89908893132841.95,
              89908893132845.81, 89908893132845.81, 89908893132845.83,
              89908893132845.83, 89908893132845.88, 89908893132845.88,
              89908893132846.02, 89908893132846.02,  89908893132847.2,
               89908893132847.2, 89908893132847.67, 89908893132847.67,
               89908893132848.5,  89908893132848.5, 89908893132855.17,
              89908893132855.17, 89908893132855.45, 89908893132855.45,
              89908893132864.62, 89908893132864.62, 89908893132868.61,
              89908893132868.61, 89908893132873.16, 89908893132873.16,
               89908893132875.6,  89908893132875.6, 89908893132875.83,
              89908893132875.83, 89908893132878.73, 89908893132878.73,
               89908893132879.9,  89908893132879.9, 89908893132880.67,
              89908893132880.67, 89908893132880.69, 89908893132880.69,
              89908893132881.31, 89908893132881.31, 89908893132881.69,
              89908893132881.69, 89908893132884.45, 89908893132884.45,
              89908893132887.27, 89908893132887.27, 89908893132887.83,
              89908893132887.83,  89908893132892.8,  89908893132892.8,
              89908893132894.34, 89908893132894.34,  89908893132894.5,
               89908893132894.5, 89908893132901.88, 89908893132901.88,
              89908893132903.27, 89908893132903.27, 89908893132904.53,
              89908893132904.53, 89908893132909.27, 89908893132909.27,
              89908893132910.38, 89908893132910.38, 89908893132911.86,
              89908893132911.86,  89908893132913.4,  89908893132913.4,
              89908893132915.73, 89908893132915.73, 89908893132916.06,
              89908893132916.06, 89908893132922.48, 89908893132922.48,
              89908893132923.44, 89908893132923.44, 89908893132924.66,
              89908893132924.66, 89908893132925.14, 89908893132925.14,
              89908893132928.28, 89908893132928.28],
             dtype='float64', name='index1')
```

I wasted time scratching my head wondering why my `groupby([`index1`,`index2`)` had produced only one level of `index1`!